# Download and save PDF using Deno

Tags: deno

Hello I want to download pdf files using deno.

I'm using

```js
export default async function downloadPDF(uid: string): Promise<void> {
   const res = await fetch(`${Deno.env.get('MY_PDF_URL')}/${uid}`);
   const file = await Deno.open(`./pdfs/${uid}.pdf`, { create: true, write: true })

   if (res?.body) {
      for await(const chunk of res.body) {
         await Deno.writeAll(file, chunk);
      }
   }
   file.close();
}
```

The command I am using is `deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-write --allow-env --allow-run main.ts`. So I don't think I havent put the right permissions here.

However I get the error

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) PermissionDenied: Permission denied (os error 13)
api_1  |    const file = await Deno.open(`./pdfs/${uid}.pdf`, { create: true, write: true })
api_1  |                 ^
api_1  |     at unwrapOpResult (deno:core/core.js:100:13)
api_1  |     at async Object.open (deno:runtime/js/40_files.js:46:17)
api_1  |     at async downloadPDF (file:///app/downloadPDF.ts:3:17)
```

What might be the issue here? I am using the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM hayd/alpine-deno:1.9.0

EXPOSE 1993

WORKDIR /app

USER deno

COPY deps.ts .
RUN deno cache deps.ts

COPY . .
RUN deno cache main.ts

CMD [run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-write --allow-env --allow-run main.ts]
```

to run this application.

Answer (score 2):

```js
import { readerFromStreamReader } from "https://deno.land/std@0.93.0/io/mod.ts";

export default async function downloadPDF(uid: string): Promise<void> {
   const res = await fetch(`https://example.com/pdfs/${uid}`);

   if (res.status !== 200) {
      console.error(`response status was ${res.status}, this is not handled.`);

      return;
   }


   // we don't want to download existing files
   if (await fileExists(`/html/${uid}.html`)) {
      console.info(`${uid}.html already exists, skipping...`);

      return;
   }

   const file = await Deno.open(`/pdfs/${uid}.pdf`, { create: true, write: true, read: true })

   if (res?.body) {
      const reader = readerFromStreamReader(res.body.getReader());
      await Deno.copy(reader, file);
   }
   file.close();
}
```

The error I posted in the question happens because of file permissions of the deno user in my `Dockerfile`. Simply removing the user solves the problem. However setting permissions correctly would be better if this is used for production.

Comment: `Deno.copy()` is deprecated now, do you know an alternative solution?

Comment: You can import `copy` from `'https://deno.land/std@0.164.0/streams/conversion.ts'`